# User friendly method of arranging replies in a site that takes the two most voted replies and place them on the top?

Tags: website-design

Basically, I'm building a site that has a liking/voting system like Youtube (it places the most voted comments on the top.

But is harder than I imagined, for instance, I've been facing the situation where the top votes are at the top of the "All the Votes" part:

> **Top Votes:**
>
> this is a comment with 5 votes
>
> this is a comment with 3 votes
>
> **All the Votes:**
>
> this is a comment with 5 votes
>
> this is a comment with 3 votes
>
> this is a comment with 2 votes
>
> this is a comment with 1 votes
>
> So you see those votes twice.

I think this is a little bit unnecessary.
I made two things so far:

1. The Top Votes are only shown if there are 10 or more replies.
2. Only replies that have 1 or more votes are shown has Top Votes.

I thought about excluding the 'Top Votes' from the 'All the Votes' part but I think this will make discussion harder to follow.

Any other suggestions to make this more user friendly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your votes are going to be displayed as ordered by votes then. It will be duplication to show the votes. As both are visible to user without change of page or scrolling.

> **Top Votes:**
>
> this is a comment with 5 votes
>
> this is a comment with 3 votes
>
> **All the Votes:**
>
> this is a comment with 5 votes <-----------Not required
>
> this is a comment with 3 votes <-----------Not required
>
> this is a comment with 2 votes
>
> this is a comment with 1 votes

But if it is not ordered by votes and are shown in chronological order then you certainly need to display. As the comments are sometimes based on previous comments. It is necessary to show all the comments so user gets the better idea.

> **Top Votes:**
>
> this is a comment with 5 votes
>
> this is a comment with 3 votes
>
> **All the Votes:**
>
> this is a comment with 2 votes
>
> this is a comment with 3 votes
>
> this is a comment with 1 votes
>
> this is a comment with 5 votes -- This comment might have reference to previous comment

Answer (score 1):

Or could you give the user the option to re-arrange the votes as they'd like. You could, for instance, remove the `Top Votes` section and show them sorted by votes at first, then the user would have means (buttons must likely) to sort by date or user rating perhaps.

**Edit**

Event the option to show the top comments could be parameterized for the user... perhaps he wants to sort them by user rating... but still show the top comments on top. I think it would be good to ask yourself what will the user be mainly looking for in the comments? Top users? Or comments people like the most? Or what?